# NSString: Best way to check if string contains another string with special format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, nsstring, substring

I have a string representing fruits, separated by dot:

```
apple.orange.banana.watermelon
```

and each fruit **may** have a tag:

```
apple.orange.[old]banana.[juicy]watermelon
```

also there **may** be fruit names which are partially overlapping:

```
apple.orange.[old]banana.[juicy]strawberry.[fresh]berry
```

also the tags may be same as fruit names:

```
apple.orange.[old]banana.[berry]strawberry.[fresh]berry
```

I need to check if such a string contains a specified fruit, so given the above string and a fruit name, say "berry", I want to know the string contains "berry" and of course it should not tell me YES if "berry"'s not there but "strawberry" is.

A quick way came up in my mind is:

1. use `componentsSeparatedByString` to get an array of components (fruit names with tags)
2. go through each component, check if it has a tag (ie square brackets), remove it if YES
3. then check the remaining string is exactly the given fruit name

I cannot just use the whole string with `rangeOfString` because "berry" is a substring of "strawberry", I can't even first get components then check substring for each component because tags may be the same as fruit names.

I wonder is there any better way to do this? Better in terms of memory footprint and/or speed?

Thanks!

Comment: Split the string once into its components. Then use the processed data for all further work with the data.

Comment: some kind of DSL? you can create a simple parser for it

Comment: @rmaddy This is what I thought, and I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: @BryanChen thanks but what is DLS?

Comment: @hzxu [Domain-specific_language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) (it should be DSL not DLS...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this.

You *could* use a regular expression.

You *could* split the string into parts.

But instead, let's notice that, when “berry” (the desired fruit) isn't the first or last fruit in the string, it's got to appear as either `]berry.` or as `.berry.`, and neither of those can match if “berry” is a substring.

So we can solve this problem quite simply putting a `.` on each end of the string before searching it for one of those patterns:

```
BOOL stringContainsFruit(NSString *string, NSString *fruit) {
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@.", string];
    NSString *dotFruit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@.", fruit];
    if ([string rangeOfString:dotFruit].location != NSNotFound) {
        return YES;
    }
    NSString *bracketFruit = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"]%@.", fruit];
    if ([string rangeOfString:bracketFruit].location != NSNotFound) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the closing curly brace of second `if` block.